# handle empty list in FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a custom widget. It is used in a `FutureBuilder`. It contains a `Text` widget. The string for this text is obtained by an api call. The json returned contains an array. This array contains objects which have a `String` property I need to access. This property populates the text widget. However there is no guarantee that the `array` will not be empty. So I need to handle the case when it is empty. At the moment I'm getting `districtOptions` was called on null and I get the purple screen.

Here is the custom widget:

```
    ElectorateWidget extends Stateless{
    final chamber2DistrictName;
    .
    .
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    .
    .

    Row(children: [Text(chamber2DistrictName,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1)]),
    .
    .

      }
    .
    .
}
```

Here is a `Column` in my FB builder that contains the custom widget and the  `Text` widget:

```
Column(
                      children: [
                        for (var lt in electorates.legislatureTypes)
                          ElectorateWidget(
                            legislatureName:
                                electorates.legislatures[lt.type].name,
                            imgUrl: electorates.legislatures[lt.type].chamber1
                                .districtOptions[0].imageUrl,
                            chamber1DistrictName: electorates
                                .legislatures[lt.type]
                                .chamber1
                                .districtOptions[0]
                                .name,
                            chamber2DistrictName: electorates
                                .legislatures[lt.type]
                                .chamber2
                                .districtOptions[0]
                                .name,
                          )
                      ],
                    ),
```

I want my builder to forget about the second chamber id the array is null. How can I do some client side checking to achieve this aim?

Comment: have you tried using snapshot.hasData while building future builder?

Comment: My snapshot has data. But one of the values is null

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ?. operator to avoid the nullpointer:

```
electorates?.legislatures[lt?.type]
    ?.chamber2
    ?.districtOptions[0]
    ?.name
```

This expression return null if any of the ?. operator is called on a null value.

Then you can check if null chamber2DistrictName is null on the custom widget to ignore it or just add a empty string.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
.
.

chamber2DistrictName != null ? 
    Row(
        children: [Text(chamber2DistrictName,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1)])
    : Container(),
.
.
}
```

Comment: Hmm, getting '[]' was called on null. Tried calling [] (0)